# How exactly does "unlock_time" work?

Tags: transaction-unlock-time

Monero transactions have something called "unlock time", that prevent transactions from being spent until a certain time in the future. I'm wondering how exactly that works.

- Can a transaction with a "unlock time" component be published to the blockchain before the unlock time?

  - If no, this means the output it is paying into is locked until that time. Can you send from that output if the transaction it is in also has a unlock time, and that unlock time is in the future?
- Can a transaction with a sooner unlock time override it, even after its on the block chain.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A transaction with a non default unlock_time will be mined as normal. However, its outputs will not be able to be used as inputs in another transaction before that time (which can be either a blockchain height, or a UNIX time in seconds).

Your second question is confusing.

You can't override a tx (except with a double spend attack sending conflicting txes to separate parts of the network), and having a non default unlock_time is irrelevant to this.

Comment: I mean can it be used as input if you the transaction spending it is also in the future?

Comment: Yes. Filler for dumb char limit script.

Comment: I mean, it's published now, unlock time is in the future?

Comment: Falls under "A transaction with a non default unlock_time will be mined as normal."